JPQL Query With Sub Select Producing Wrong SQL
@Query("select q.x from (select 1 as x) q") 
Generated: select q.x from (select 1) q(x) 
Expected: select q.x from (select 1 as x) q
Hibernate Version: 6.4.1
JPA: 3.2.2
@Query("select q.x from (select 1 as x) q")
Generated: select q.x from (select 1) q(x)
Expected: select q.x from (select 1 as x) q

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
